Toggling form submission in Vuetify with Composition API
Vuetify's documentation states that "[v-form]'s current validation status is accessed using v-model or the submit event". Trying to use this to toggle the submit button locks out the submit button regardless of whether or not the form is valid; a toy example is given below.
<script setup>
var valid = false
const required = [(v) => !!v || 'Required.']
</script>

<template>
  <v-form v-model="valid">
    <v-text-field :rules="required"></v-text-field>
    <v-btn :disabled="!valid"></v-btn>
  </v-form>
</template>

No combination of validate-on caused the button to correctly re-enable once the text field was filled.
If the intuitive method of toggling the submit button doesn't do anything, what's the correct way of achieving this effect using the Composition API? All the examples I've seen achieving this either use Vue 2 or the Options API.

Your v-model variable is not reactive
var valid = false

You need to use ref.  Review Reactivity Fundamentals from Vue documentation.  Also, var is very outdated. Use either const or let, and for refs you should always use const because it's only the inner value that is ever updated.
import { ref } from 'vue'

const valid = ref(false)

